# How to give conditions to Rand()

Tags: c++

First time on stack overflow.

I have this assignment due for class where we have a guessing game where our program has to generate a string of Uppercase letters of n length and n different defined by the user. I got most of my assignment working but when generate the string I am lost with how I could put these conditions in place for it to work.

```
char create_sequence(){
   return rand() % 26 + 65;
}
```

Do you have any tips?

Comment: So you need a string of `n` unique random characters?

Comment: The string is a generated string of n different characters for instance if n= 3 only 3 characters can be used to make this string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, personally I think you are not far from the answer:

```
rand() % 26 + 65
```

Will effectively returns an uppercase ASCII letter. As long as you initialize the random seed once `srand (time(NULL));`, you can then call your instruction as many times as you want to get random values. So all you miss is a simple loop. Here is an example for 5 characters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */


char randomChar(){
   return rand() % 26 + 65;
}

std::string randomString(int length)
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    std::string rc("");
    for(int i=0; i<length; ++i)
    {
        rc += randomChar();
    }
    return rc;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Random string (x5) is " << randomString(5) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know sequence length, you don't need amount of different characters. This is because you require `length <= characters`.

To create sequence of `n` unique characters write a separate function:

```
vector<char> create_sequence(int n) {
    vector<char> letters;
    for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch) {
        letters.push_back(ch);
    }

    vector<char> sequence;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int index = rand() % letters.size();
        sequence.push_back(letters[index]);
        letters.erase(letters.begin() + index, letters.begin() + index + 1);
    }

    return sequence;
}
```